# Pulling Data of Pointer Field of PFUser.currentUser in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I am writing an iOS app with Swift using Parse.

In my **User** table, I have a pointer field called **UserAddress** which is pointing to an **Address** table record. I would like to pull this **Address** data for **current user**. I did a bit of research and figured out fetching in background is an option but I would like to avoid it. Is there an alternative to pull this data without running extra fetch work?

What I can imagine is:

- Fetching pointer data in AppDelegate before the app gets ready to use for users.
- Somehow, force to set **includeKey** when loading a **currentUser**

Any of the above is feasible? Please advise me.

Answer (score 1):

You correctly understand the two options, and they are the only two options.  For non-user objects, usually `includeKey()` on a query is the way to go.

For the current user, since you have the user already, it would seem a little strange to query the user, including the pointer, just to avoid fetching the pointer, but that would work.  You might be better off working on whatever's making you hesitant to do the `fetch()`.